# can we change name for chronicle-queue data files?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

when i use OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue, it creates data files in queue with name format as today's date.
for example : 20180113.cq4
can we change this file naming convention ?

Comment: Generally these files are in a directory by themselves.  Can you outline the use case for changing the file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not change the name of the queue files. If you do, chronicle-queue won’t see them. The file naming convention is not configurable. If you changed chronicle queue code to make it configurable and issue a pull request we could merge in this change.